# Python how to replace values in one list with values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

example:

my list is `['tree'，'world'，'tre'，'worl']`

my dict is `{'tre':'good','worl':nice}`

my scripts:

```
def replace(list, dictionary):
    for i in list:
        for k in dictionary:
            list = list.replace(k, dictionary[k])
    return list
print replace(input_file,curaw_dict)
```

but every time I receive the result is like：

```
goode
niced
good
nice
```

how can I make it more accurate
make it like

```
tree
world
good
nice
```

Thanks alot

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It sqashed the function of the same name

Comment: I don't believe that you've run the code you've entered. `list` has no method called `replace`. Please create the shortest possible program that accurately demonstrates the error and copy-paste (never retype) that program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: What are those commas in the first list?

Answer (score 6):

Lets make it a list comprehension instead.

```
replaced_list = [x if x not in my_dict else my_dict[x] for x in my_list]
```

I guess if you want a function you could do:

```
replace = lambda my_dict, my_list: [x if x not in my_dict else my_dict[x] for x in my_list]
```

or

```
def replace(my_list, my_dict):
    return [x if x not in my_dict else my_dict[x] for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input_file = ['tree', 'world', 'tre', 'worl']
curaw_dict = {'tre':'good','worl':'nice'}

def replace(list, dictionary):
    return [curaw_dict.get(item, item) for item in list]
print replace(input_file,curaw_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> li=['tree', 'world', 'tre', 'worl']
>>> di={'tre':'good','worl':'nice'}
>>> print('\n'.join(di.get(e,e) for e in li))
tree
world
good
nice
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

`for k in dictionary:` is not the correct way to iterate over the items in the dictionary. Instead, you should use `enumerate` to iterate over the items in the list and look them up in the dictionary:

```
def replace(lst, dictionary):
    for k,v in enumerate(lst):
        if v in dictionary:
            lst[k] = dictionary[v]
    return lst
```

For each item in the list, k is the index of the value and v is the value itself. You then check if the value is in the dictionary, and if it is, you replace the value in the list with the value in the dictionary.

You also should not name your variables `list`, since that is a reserved word in Python.

You can alternatively use a list comprehension:

```
def replace(lst, dictionary):
    return [item if not item in dictionary else dictionary[item] for item in lst]
```

Comment: A few remarks: 1) `list` isn’t a reserved word. It’s just the class name for a built-in, and like any other name, it gets shadowed by other scopes. 2) `for k in dictionary` is a correct way to iterate over a dictionary; it’s just not the best one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(list, dictionary):
    for idx, val in enumerate(list):
        if i in k:
           list[idx] = dictionary[list[idx]]
    return list
print replace(input_file,curaw_dict)
```

You don't need to iterate over a dictionary. Replace does partial replacements, but `in` will check if a key exists in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`'key' in dictionary` is the way to check if a key exists in a dict:

```
def replace(list, dictionary):
    new_list = []

    for i in list:
        if i in dictionary:
            new_list.append(dictionary[i])
        else:
          new_list.append(i)

    return new_list
```